# DBeaver - Non sequential when executing multiple oracle inserts

Tags: oracle, sql-insert, dbeaver

I'm using latest DBeaver with Oracle 12

I need to run several inserts to different tables that are connected by foreign key

When executing multiple oracle inserts (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> ) to several tables and it failed on foreign key when it shouldn't (if executed sequentially).

Executing same SQLs in PLSQL developer doesn't produce any error. (reproducible)

It seems that the inserts aren't execute in sequence

Can this behavior changed?

Found [DBeaver wiki](https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/SQL-Execution/) that warns for unexpected results

> NOTE: Be careful with this feature. If you execute a huge script with a large number of queries, it might cause unexpected problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found in [disucssions](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/discussions/14787) solution to add inserts to PL/SQL block:

> ShadelessFox
> It's not possible from a DBeaver perspective, but you can use PL/SQL blocks